# Google Play Download Statistic

Tags: android, google-play

When you browse Google Play in browser, you will see the installs statistic with a graph at the right side of the page. What does that installs mean? Is it lifetime total install of that app? Or it is the last 30 days of install of that app?

Also, Google Play categories the Top Free, Top Paid, Top Grossing, Top New Paid, and Top New Free. What duration it based off? By last week top? Or last 30 days top?

Is there a way that we can sort and view all time top most popular apps?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it lifetime total install of that app? Or it is the last 30 days of install of that app?

The graph is for the last 30 days, but the numbers range (10,000 - 50,000 for example) is for the lifetime of the app.

Nobody is really sure how the top categories are decided, but I'm guessing its a combination of Downloads and ratings (for a specific amount of time, in case of the New categories, like maybe a week or a month).